# How can i make this also be able to filter by arrangement type?

Tags: php, eloquent

I need some help with the final piece of my eternal puzzle :P

I have this code:

```
<?php

require_once 'connection.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$skoleListe = Skole::all();
$arrangementsListe = Arrangement::all();
$skoleAttributter = '';
$arrangementsAttributter = '';

$skoleIsSet = '';

if(isset($_GET['skoleId']))
{
    $skoleIsSet = $_GET['skoleId'];
}

else {
    echo 'Velg skole!';
}


foreach($skoleListe as $skole)
{
    $skoleAttributter.= '<option value="index.php?skoleId=' . $skole['id'] . 
'">' . $skole['navn'] . '</option>';
 }

foreach($arrangementsListe as $arrangement)
{
$arrangementsAttributter.= '<option value="index.php?skoleId=' . $skoleIsSet 
. "&arrangement=" . $arrangement['type'] . '">' . $arrangement['type'] . 
'</option>';
}

 ?>


<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location= this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="">Velg campus</option>
    <?= $skoleAttributter; ?>
</select>

<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location= this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="">Velg arrangementstype</option>
    <?= $arrangementsAttributter; ?>
</select>

<?php


$Arrangementer = Arrangement::with('skoler')->get();
$skoleId = '';
$arrangementIsSet = isset($_GET['arrangement']);
$skoleIsSet = isset($_GET['skoleId']);

if(isset($_GET['skoleId'])) {
    $skoleId = $_GET['skoleId'];
    foreach ($Arrangementer as $arrangement) {
        if ($arrangement['skole_id'] == $skoleId) {
            include 'card.php';

        }
    }
}
```

My card.php looks like this:

```
<h2><?= $arrangement['overskrift'] ?></h2>
<p>Sted: <?= $arrangement['sted'] ?></p>
```

The idea is to sort arrangements according to schools.
I have tried with various if/else statements without luck.

Any ideas how I can do this? And any general advices on how I can make my code more effective? Btw, I am using the Eloquent library.

Comment: well, what are the models that define `Arrangements` and `Schools`? and what do you mean by *The idea is to sort arrangements according to schools*?

Comment: *Any ideas how I can do this?* is not a meaningful question, and neither is *any general advices?*.